# Scala List logic

Tags: scala

I have list (2,5,7,15,10) and expected result is (2,10,70,1050,10500) actually it is multiplication of its previous elements for example (2, 2* 5, 2*5*7, 2*5*7*15, 2*5*7*15*10). I tried this half baked solution but it seems i am getting confused with foldLeft.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
val lis =   List(2, 5, 7, 15, 10)               //> lis  : List[Int] = List(2, 5, 7, 15, 10)
 lis.head                                     //> res0: Int = 2
 lis.drop(1)                                  //> res1: List[Int] = List(5, 7, 15, 10)
 lis.tail                                     //> res2: List[Int] = List(5, 7, 15, 10)
 lis.drop(1).foldLeft(lis) {

         (r,c) =>
         println(r,c)
         r.tail



 }                                            //> (List(2, 5, 7, 15, 10),5)
                                              //| (List(5, 7, 15, 10),7)
                                              //| (List(7, 15, 10),15)
                                              //| (List(15, 10),10)
                                              //| res3: List[Int] = List(10)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to approach this problem is to use `inits`:

```
scala> val list = List(2, 5, 7, 15, 10)
list: List[Int] = List(2, 5, 7, 15, 10)

scala> list.inits.foreach(println)
List(2, 5, 7, 15, 10)
List(2, 5, 7, 15)
List(2, 5, 7)
List(2, 5)
List(2)
List()
```

Which suggests the following one-liner:

```
scala> list.inits.map(_.product).toList.init.reverse
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 10, 70, 1050, 10500)
```

It's also possible to solve this a little more concisely and efficiently with `scanLeft`:

```
scala> list.scanLeft(1)(_ * _).tail
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 10, 70, 1050, 10500)
```

In general if you have something like a fold but want to hold on to the intermediate accumulated values, `scanLeft` is the way to go.

Comment: The last line with scanLeft is aboslutely brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can fold into a `List`:

```
list.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { 
  case (Nil, x) => List(x)
  case (head :: tail, x) => (head*x) :: head :: tail
}.reverse
```